# Differences between Permutations and Combinations

Tags: permutations, combinations

I am a little confused by these questions, I have a very basic understanding of them but I am hoping that someone might be able to explain them to me a little better.

There are ten different types of pens (example: 1 with blue ink, 1 with black ink etc.) that a company offers in their production line. This is true for all the questions below:

1. You need to order all your pens for each day of the week on one single day (and have them delivered on that day). It does not mater what type of pens you get, but you need to make sure you have one for every day of the week. How many orders are now possible?

   - I am assuming this would be something like 10 choose 7.
2. The pen company offers you a special with 2 blue inked pens, 3 red inked pens, and 2 black inked pens which are to be delivered one per day for the entire week. How many orders are possible if you need to tell the company what pens you want and on what day.
3. You need to order 7 pens on one single day, and have them delivered on that day. You now need a different pen for each day of the week How many orders are possible?

Thank you for any help ahead of time!

Comment: It ultimately comes down to whether different orderings are different to the effect of the situation at hand: for a small example of 3 pens and $2$ days: If you get, say blue in day one and red in day $2$ , do you consider this to be the same as getting $red $ in day $1$ and blue in day $2$? If they are different, use permutations; if not, use combinations.

Comment: The answer to number 3 would be 10 choose 7 (assuming that, by "different pen", you mean "different type of pen").  Number 1 is more challenging since you can get two or more of the same type.  You would use the stars and bars technique for that one (which in the end uses combinations, but not 10 choose 7).

Comment: For number 2, what do you mean by "you need to tell the company what pens you want"?  If you just mean that you need to tell them on which days to deliver which colors, than that one uses a multinomial coefficient.  In none of these problems is the distinction between permutations and combinations the main issue.

Comment: @WillOrrick (in your fist comment) Yes, they should be different types of pens. To answer your second comment's question: "you need to tell the company what pens you want" means to tell them on what day to deliver the pen. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For number $1,$ you need to specify seven not necessarily different pen types taken from a set of $10$ possible types.  Arrangement doesn't matter since the pens are all to be delivered on one day.  If the pen types are $A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J$ then examples of valid pen orders would be sequences like $BCDEFGH$ or $AAAAAAA$ or $AACCEEG.$  You can use the [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) technique to count these.  The "bars" are separator marks between different types.  So the sequence $BCDEFGH$ could be written $\mid B\mid C\mid D\mid E\mid F\mid G\mid H\mid\mid$.  You can think of the bars as divisions between different "bins", one bin for each type of pen.  In this example, the $A$ bin is empty, as are the $I$ and $J$ bins.  The sequence $AACCEEG$ could be written $AA\mid\mid CC\mid\mid EE\mid\mid G\mid\mid\mid$.  Since a sequence is specified by saying how many items each bin contains, the letters can all be replaced with a single symbol,  say a star.  So the first example would be represented by $\mid *\mid *\mid *\mid *\mid *\mid *\mid *\mid\mid,$ which indicates that the $B,C,D,E,F,G,$ and $H$ bins each contain one item, while the second example would be represented by $**\mid\mid **\mid\mid **\mid\mid *\mid\mid\mid,$ which indicates that the $A,C,$ and $E$ bins each contain two items and the $G$ bin contains one item.  Observe that since there are $10$ bins, there will always be nine bars.  Since there are seven items, there will always be seven stars.  So it remains to enumerate the number of sequences with nine bars and seven stars, which can be done using combinations.

For number $2,$ the numbers of pens of each color to be delivered are fixed.  The only thing that needs to be specified are the days on which blue pens are to be delivered, the days on which red pens are to be delivered, and the days on which black pens are to be delivered.  You can think of this as a process of choosing days of the week: first pick two days for delivery of blue pens, then pick three from the remaining days for the delivery of red pens, and finally pick two from the remaining days for the delivery of black pens.  Alternatively, using $B$ for blue, $R$ for red, and $K$ for black, you need to find all arrangements of the sequence $BBRRRKK.$  The answer to this is a multinomial coefficient.

Number $3$ is more straightforward: since the pens are to be delivered on one day, you are merely choosing seven different types from a set of $10$ possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

It actually depends. If the pens are indifferent, use combinations. If not, use permutations. Some problems, like the second one, use a combination of both. Good luck! Ask me if you need more help.